# Search using Slug as query parameter

Tags: search, entry-slug

I created Search that uses entry slug, but it fails if the slug has more than one dash "-" in it. Has anyone come across this and/or have any ideas for getting around it?

I need to use the slug because they are unique within a section.

Comment: Can you add a sample of the code you're using?

Comment: It is a simple search: I set a variable called "q" and use that as the search parameter, e.g.  craft,entries,section('rides').search(q) If that variable contains more than one dash it does not return anything - if I edit the slug to one dash it works fine

Answer (score 1):

If you know your **q** variable should be a slug, you can use the `.slug` query parameter:

```
{# Get the requested entry slug from the URL #}
{% set requestedSlug = craft.app.request.getSegment(3) %}

{# Fetch the entry with that slug #}
{% set entry = craft.entries()
    .slug(requestedSlug|literal)
    .one() %}
```

[More on how to use this in the Craft 3 docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/entry-queries.html#slug).

I have personally had some unexpected results using Craft's built-in search.

Comment: Thanks, Alex . I ended up taking a different approach using relatedTo. Appreciate your response!